# Como eliminar un header('Location: 'http://www.example.com/', true, 301);

Tags: php

me cree un `header('Location: 'http://www.example.com/', true, 301);` para que cuando un usuario haga session ya no pueda ingresar al formulario de login pero ahora cuando quiero cambiar la dirección del header, me sigue enviando al mismo http://www.example.com/, como puedo eliminar el header 301

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente `header('Location: http://url');` no se puede cancelar, es uno de los casos especiales que indica la documentación de PHP

http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php